# How do I fully remove travis from my github repo?

Tags: github, travis-ci

This is very frustrating. I've done everything to remove travis that I can think of. Still, every PR has the check "continuous-integration/travis-ci Expected — Waiting for status to be reported Required"

In my Settings > Integrations and Services, Travis CI is there but there's no way to configure it. I've tried everything, removed the repo from the Travis side, removed `.travis.yml`, and I am out of ideas. Does anyone know what I can do? Thanks!

[image: travis is stalling on every PR]

[image: there is no way to remove the service in settings]

Comment: Is this selected as a required check for protected branches?

Answer (score 7):

https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-required-status-checks/

Your repo still has status checks enabled.